# Can't get ArrayList<String> from my intent

Tags: java, android, string, arraylist

MainActivity.java:

```
Intent orderIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OrderActivity.class);
orderIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("numstrlist", numbers);
startActivity(orderIntent);
```

OrderActivity.java:

```
ArrayList<String> numbersI = i.getStringArrayListExtra("numstrlist");
```

What's going on? I can't get the ArrayList and don't know why.

Comment: What do you mean by "can't get"? Did compilation error occur? Did runtime exception occur? What was the exception?

Comment: Exactly, it says java.lang.nullpointerexception.

Comment: getStringArrayListExtra() returns null if there's no array list to be retrieved. We really need to see more code to see if you've accidentally removed the array list in your MainActivity (or someplace else) before attempting to retrieve it in the object which receives your intent. In fact, we don't even have enough evidence to see if you're dealing with the same Intent on both sides.

Comment: `ArrayList<String> numbers = new ArrayList<String>();`

Comment: I'm sure I didn't remove the arraylist because I don't have a compilation error

Comment: paste your code in more detail...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think nullpointerexception is throws due to "i",as all seems right....
have you do something like this

```
Intent i=getIntent();
```

before

```
ArrayList<String> numbersI = i.getStringArrayListExtra("numstrlist");
```

you need to try the solution provided by utpal..or directly use

```
ArrayList<String> numbersI=getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("numstrlist");
```

Comment: `Intent i = getIntent();`
`ArrayList<String> numbersI = new ArrayList<String>(i.getExtras().getStringArrayList("numstrlist"));`
That's how I did but it doesn't work.

Comment: so,does the problem solved? your logic seems right.i think something other than that part is going wrong.why won't you put your project on github to analyse.

Comment: Whole project...put it on the git hub..if possible??

Comment: I'm getting Git for Windows, gonna upload it soon

Comment: Can you explain me how to upload the whole project into github?

Comment: you haven't set view for OrderActivity i.e. setContentView(R.layout.activity_order); hence throws nullpointerexception

Comment: Just noticed that. Thank you!

Comment: your welcome....but be careful...how can u get the view(button,textview,listview etc) if layout-view is not set...its always throw null pointer exception...

Comment: I changed that and it's still not working :(, updated github check it out

Comment: ok let me push your modified code into my github account and you check it .... here it's working

Comment: ohhh..sorry,...i've forgot to tell u...that u have to initialise the var i,b,numbersI inside onCreate method..

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
ArrayList<String> numbersI = i.getStringArrayListExtra("numstrlist");
```

Try this

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
ArrayList<String> numbersI = bundle.getStringArrayList("numstrlist");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayList("yourkey")
```